# Time difference giving error

Tags: r

I have two time of same date "2015/09/12 00:02:18" and "2015/09/12 23:59:39" .

How to calculate difference between these two time frames?

Comment: witch language you would use php? javascript ?

Comment: No no.. this is in R

Answer (score 3):

You can try to convert the strings into POSIXct and simply calculate the difference:

```
t1 <- "2015/09/12 00:02:18"
t2 <- "2015/09/12 23:59:39"
> as.POSIXct(t2) - as.POSIXct(t1)
#Time difference of 23.95583 hours
```

Alternatively you may use `difftime()`, a function used to calculate time differences:

```
> difftime(t2, t1)
#Time difference of 23.95583 hours
```

If you don't want to have the text in the output, you can obtain the time difference in hours with

```
> unclass(difftime(t2, t1, units="hours"))[1]
#[1] 23.95583
```

Comment: Thanks,

yes that is true. But please check the time it is  "2015/09/12 00:02:18" , that is night 12AM and "2015/09/12 23:59:39" ,which is night 11:59PM  .. But the difference is 23.95 hours.. Is it right?? 
 I think this is wrong value what we are getting.. it should be some minutes.. Right??

Comment: It's the same date, isn't it...? The result looks correct to me.

Comment: 23.95583 hours is not the right answer... it should be 3 minutes 21 second.

Comment: @BibhutiBhusanSahoo You are mistaken, this *is* the correct answer. Again, the hours refer to the same day. If we were comparing 00:02:18 of one day to 23:59:39 of the **previous** day, then the difference would be 02 minutes and 39 seconds. But in the OP the dates are identical, and hence the correct time difference is slightly less than 24 hours.

Comment: Oh .. I am so sorry.. Yes Yes .. Thanks dude... a little silly mistake... Thanks again...