# difference between columns with time in r

Tags: r, time

I've a data frame in which there are two columns with in and out time, I'm trying to get the time difference in seconds in another column.

```
 ` ## intime ##     |s  ## outtime ##

 1. 6/20/2017 1:47  |s  6/20/2017 1:47
 2. 6/20/2017 3:32  |s  6/20/2017 3:32
 3. 6/20/2017 21:45 |s  6/20/2017 21:45
 4. 6/23/2017 0:15  |s 6/23/2017 0:15
 5. 6/17/2017 1:30  |s 6/17/2017 1:30`
```

I tried using

```
 `t<-c(m1$intime)
  t1<-c(m1$outime)
  dt <- as.POSIXct(t)
#Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(t) : 'origin' must be supplied
  dt <- as.POSIXct(t1)
#Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(t1) : 'origin' must be supplied`
```

tried using the code in the link [time difference giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036306/time-difference-giving-error?rq=1)

`difftime(t2, t1)
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

not sure where I'm going wrong. The columns are integer type.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> x=c("6/20/2017 1:47")
> library(lubridate)
> y=mdy_hm(x)
> y
[1] "2017-06-20 01:47:00 UTC"
```

so going by the given data

```
df1$intime=mdy_hm(df1$intime)
df1$outtime-mdy_hm(df1$outime)
df$timefidd=difftime(df1$intime,df1$outtime,units='secs')
```

Comment: I'm getting warning below each code line `Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Comment: check name of variables. mine uses outtime, yours uses outime

Comment: I checked that it is not giving the same error, I copied your lines and edited my column names, secondly it is throw's NA NA... all the way.

Comment: When I run the below code for one row it works
`> x <- as.POSIXct("2017-06-20 01:47")
> x1 <- as.POSIXct("2017-06-20 05:47")
#difftime(x1,x, units="secs")
#Time difference of 14400 secs
> difftime(x1,x, units="min")
#Time difference of 240 mins`

It is not working when I give the whole dataframe$column

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here.

If your columns are integers, then `as.POSIXct` will interpret them as the number of seconds since a specific time, which is defined by the `origin` argument that the error is referencing.

If your columns are characters but not in a standard format, it's necessary to tell `as.POSIXct` how to interpret the different parts of the character string.

Here is an example from `?as.POSIXct`:

`as.POSIXct("2011-03-27 01:30:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

If your columns actually look like `"6/20/2017 1:47"`, then you should be able to use:

`as.POSIXct("6/20/2017 1:47", format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')`

or

`as.POSIXct(m1$intime, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')`

But it's unclear how your columns can be integers and still look like the table you have posted.

Comment: I tried to give my data frame it is giving the below error
      `> as.POSIXct(t1, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  [41] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  [81] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`

Comment: not sure why but I get a perfect table as I'm reading it from a excel web query, when I hit `typeof(m1$intime)` it shows them as integer

Comment: At this point, it would depend on the nature of the column. It would help to get the full reproducible code for how you are reading the data. I'd also be careful using `typeof`, you should be using `class` or something similar instead. For example `typeof(as.POSIXct("6/20/2017 1:47", format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))` gives `double` even though it was just defined as POSIX.

Comment: @KKY Adding tag as I'm not sure if you are automatically notified when I comment.

Comment: you are right it gives double on my original data as well and class is returning a factor type

Comment: @KKY I don't think it's just a factor issue though. The following seems to work: `as.POSIXct(factor('6/20/2017 1:47'), format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')`, so reproducible code would still be required.

Answer (score 0):

The error says everything you need to move forward.  `as.POSIX*` gives you an error because you don't have the standart date format. Check the function `?strptime`. Also, [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/28038_1bcb9aa80ca84f27ace07d612872861a.html) is a good article about dates in R

Comment: @ssokolen, thanks the code is working now, I'm not sure why it thre the error earlier